# How to change number automatically after every 5 seconds

Tags: laravel

I am trying to change the number automatically after every five seconds between 1 to 90.
Here is my code,

```
public function getNumber(Request $request)
    {
        $numbers = rand(1, 90);
        $data = array('message'=>ResponseMessage::statusResponses(ResponseMessage::_STATUS_DATA_FOUND), 'number'=>$numbers);
        return $this->sendSuccessResponse($data);
    }
```

Now, when I hit this I am getting the number between 1 to 90. I am getting different numbers whenever I hit.

But now, I just want that, when I hit it. It will start and after every 5 seconds number will change automatically.

Can we do that, if yes, please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you can use javascript for this and call your function or send ajax rewuest to your controller there:

```
window.setInterval(function(){
  /// call your function here
}, 5000);
```

it will run every 5 secs

and for stop that :

```
clearInterval()
```

Comment: Can we do only inside controller,

Comment: no. you need to write this js function and inside that, call your laravel route using ajax and then in your controller return your number and use it in blade

Comment: Actually, I am trying this in API, so there is no blade.

Comment: so you need to use task scheduling in laravel read this: 
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/scheduling

Comment: is ther any other option ?

Comment: i don't think so

Comment: its looking quite typical, as I haven't worked on cron jobs earlier